# Custom Post Type and Taxonomy pagination permalink

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

I have a custom post type of galleries with pagination for the posts thumbnails.
It worked great until I activated the permalinks in the WP admin panel.

I saw many posts on this problem but none of them helped me solve this problem.

Here is the link to my gallery:
[Heseg website](http://heseg.com/gallery/pic-of-the-week/?lang=en)

Thanks

Comment: There is a 301 redirect from `gallery/pic-of-the-week/page/2/?lang=en` to `http://heseg.com/gallery/pic-of-the-week/?lang=en`. I can't tell why but that is not normal. You will need to find that. Disable your plugins and check your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Do you know what precisely implements pagination at your site? Is it theme, plugin?